# GL_APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch gl_lastFragData

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

Apple introduced a new shader extension called GL_APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch, which allows fully programmable blending. There is also a wwdc video explaining the functionallity. It's the video 513 of wwdc 2012.

Sadly this extension doesn’t work for me.

F-Shader:

```
#extension GL_APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = gl_lastFragData[0] + vec4(colorVarying.x, colorVarying.y, colorVarying.z, 1.0);
}
```

Debug output:
extension ‘GL_APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch’ is not supported

Tried to run it on the iOS 6.0 iPad Simulator ‘n on an actual iPad with 6.0

How can that be? What do I have to do to actually use this extension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` it was called `GL_APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch` in the Beta, but it got renamed in the final release (according to the [iOS6 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS6.html)).

Comment: Excellent, thank u very much! Also it's gl_LastFragData instead of gl_lastFragData.